# T-SQL function to convert JSON to XML

Tags: json, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to convert into XML this JSON data:

https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2019-07-20&end_at=2019-07-26&base=CAD&symbols=USD

I am using the function shown in the code below, which I got from here:

https://sqlsunday.com/2013/05/12/converting-json-data-to-xml-using-a-t-sql-function/

But it does not work and I get the error message shown below.

What modifications need to be made to the code in the function so that it converts the above JSON data into XML?

Here is the function I have tried:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_parse_json2xml(
    @json    varchar(max)
)
RETURNS xml
AS

BEGIN;
    DECLARE @output varchar(max), @key varchar(max), @value varchar(max),
        @recursion_counter int, @offset int, @nested bit, @array bit,
        @tab char(1)=CHAR(9), @cr char(1)=CHAR(13), @lf char(1)=CHAR(10);

    --- Clean up the JSON syntax by removing line breaks and tabs and
    --- trimming the results of leading and trailing spaces:
    SET @json=LTRIM(RTRIM(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@json, @cr, ''), @lf, ''), @tab, '')));

    --- Sanity check: If this is not valid JSON syntax, exit here.
    IF (LEFT(@json, 1)!='{' OR RIGHT(@json, 1)!='}')
        RETURN '';

    --- Because the first and last characters will, by definition, be
    --- curly brackets, we can remove them here, and trim the result.
    SET @json=LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)-2)));

    SELECT @output='';
    WHILE (@json!='') BEGIN;

        --- Look for the first key which should start with a quote.
        IF (LEFT(@json, 1)!='"')
            RETURN 'Expected quote (start of key name). Found "'+
                LEFT(@json, 1)+'"';

        --- .. and end with the next quote (that isn't escaped with
        --- and backslash).
        SET @key=SUBSTRING(@json, 2,
            PATINDEX('%[^\\]"%', SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json))+' "'));

        --- Truncate @json with the length of the key.
        SET @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, LEN(@key)+3, LEN(@json)));

        --- The next character should be a colon.
        IF (LEFT(@json, 1)!=':')
            RETURN 'Expected ":" after key name, found "'+
                LEFT(@json, 1)+'"!';

        --- Truncate @json to skip past the colon:
        SET @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)));

        --- If the next character is an angle bracket, this is an array.
        IF (LEFT(@json, 1)='[')
            SELECT @array=1, @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)));

        IF (@array IS NULL) SET @array=0;
        WHILE (@array IS NOT NULL) BEGIN;

            SELECT @value=NULL, @nested=0;
            --- The first character of the remainder of @json indicates
            --- what type of value this is.

            --- Set @value, depending on what type of value we're looking at:
            ---
            --- 1. A new JSON object:
            ---    To be sent recursively back into the parser:
            IF (@value IS NULL AND LEFT(@json, 1)='{') BEGIN;
                SELECT @recursion_counter=1, @offset=1;
                WHILE (@recursion_counter!=0 AND @offset<LEN(@json)) BEGIN;
                    SET @offset=@offset+
                        PATINDEX('%[{}]%', SUBSTRING(@json, @offset+1,
                            LEN(@json)));
                    SET @recursion_counter=@recursion_counter+
                        (CASE SUBSTRING(@json, @offset, 1)
                            WHEN '{' THEN 1
                            WHEN '}' THEN -1 END);
                END;

                SET @value=CAST(
                    dbo.fn_parse_json2xml(LEFT(@json, @offset))
                        AS varchar(max));
                SET @json=SUBSTRING(@json, @offset+1, LEN(@json));
                SET @nested=1;
            END

            --- 2a. Blank text (quoted)
            IF (@value IS NULL AND LEFT(@json, 2)='""')
                SELECT @value='', @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 3,
                    LEN(@json)));

            --- 2b. Other text (quoted, but not blank)
            IF (@value IS NULL AND LEFT(@json, 1)='"') BEGIN;
                SET @value=SUBSTRING(@json, 2,
                    PATINDEX('%[^\\]"%',
                        SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json))+' "'));
                SET @json=LTRIM(
                    SUBSTRING(@json, LEN(@value)+3, LEN(@json)));
            END;

            --- 3. Blank (not quoted)
            IF (@value IS NULL AND LEFT(@json, 1)=',')
                SET @value='';

            --- 4. Or unescaped numbers or text.
            IF (@value IS NULL) BEGIN;
                SET @value=LEFT(@json,
                    PATINDEX('%[,}]%', REPLACE(@json, ']', '}')+'}')-1);
                SET @json=SUBSTRING(@json, LEN(@value)+1, LEN(@json));
            END;

            --- Append @key and @value to @output:
            SET @output=@output+@lf+@cr+
                REPLICATE(@tab, @@NESTLEVEL-1)+
                '<'+@key+'>'+
                    ISNULL(REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(@value, '\"', '"'), '\\', '\'), '')+
                    (CASE WHEN @nested=1
                        THEN @lf+@cr+REPLICATE(@tab, @@NESTLEVEL-1)
                        ELSE ''
                    END)+
                '</'+@key+'>';
            --- And again, error checks:
            ---
            --- 1. If these are multiple values, the next character
            ---    should be a comma:
            IF (@array=0 AND @json!='' AND LEFT(@json, 1)!=',')
                RETURN @output+'Expected "," after value, found "'+
                    LEFT(@json, 1)+'"!';
            --- 2. .. or, if this is an array, the next character
            --- should be a comma or a closing angle bracket:
            IF (@array=1 AND LEFT(@json, 1) NOT IN (',', ']'))
                RETURN @output+'In array, expected "]" or "," after '+
                    'value, found "'+LEFT(@json, 1)+'"!';
            --- If this is where the array is closed (i.e. if it's a
            --- closing angle bracket)..
            IF (@array=1 AND LEFT(@json, 1)=']') BEGIN;
                SET @array=NULL;
                SET @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)));

                --- After a closed array, there should be a comma:
                IF (LEFT(@json, 1) NOT IN ('', ',')) BEGIN
                    RETURN 'Closed array, expected ","!';
                END;
            END;

            SET @json=LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@json, 2, LEN(@json)+1));
            IF (@array=0) SET @array=NULL;

        END;
    END;

    --- Return the output:
    RETURN CAST(@output AS xml);
END;
```

The expected result is XML data. The actual result so far has been the error message below:

Msg 9455, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
XML parsing: line 3, character 3, illegal qualified name character

Comment: Starting with v2016 there is native JSON-support. Things would be much easier then... And you might want to read my comment below the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that XML tag names cannot begin with a number, but the keys in this JSON are dates ("2019-07-23", etc).

To workaround that problem, we can add a character before the keys that begin with a number, by adding the following line:

```
            IF @key LIKE '[0-9]%' SET @key='date'+@key
```

before the line that says:

```
            --- Append @key and @value to @output:
```

This way, we get the following XML:

```
<rates>
  <date2019-07-23>
    <USD>0.7605336601</USD>
  </date2019-07-23>
  <date2019-07-25>
    <USD>0.7617709547</USD>
  </date2019-07-25>
  <date2019-07-26>
    <USD>0.758719346</USD>
  </date2019-07-26>
  <date2019-07-24>
    <USD>0.7616052506</USD>
  </date2019-07-24>
  <date2019-07-22>
    <USD>0.7647459939</USD>
  </date2019-07-22>
</rates>
<start_at>2019-07-20</start_at>
<base>CAD</base>
<end_at>2019-07-26</end_at>
```

*LATER EDIT:*

Shnugo correctly pointed out in the comments that using tag names to carry information is a bad idea. It would be better to move that information in an attribute. To do this, you can replace the relevant portion of the function with this code:

```
        DECLARE @attribute VARCHAR(max)
        IF @key LIKE '[0-9]%' SELECT @attribute=@key, @key='rate'
        ELSE SET @attribute=NULL

        --- Append @key and @value to @output:
        SET @output=@output+@lf+@cr+
            REPLICATE(@tab, @@NESTLEVEL-1)+
            '<'+@key+ISNULL(' date="'+@attribute+'"','')+'>'+
                ISNULL(REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(@value, '\"', '"'), '\\', '\'), '')+
                (CASE WHEN @nested=1
                    THEN @lf+@cr+REPLICATE(@tab, @@NESTLEVEL-1)
                    ELSE ''
                END)+
            '</'+@key+'>';
```

This way, we get the following XML:

```
<rates>
  <date value="2019-07-23">
    <USD>0.7605336601</USD>
  </date>
  <date value="2019-07-25">
    <USD>0.7617709547</USD>
  </date>
  <date value="2019-07-26">
    <USD>0.758719346</USD>
  </date>
  <date value="2019-07-24">
    <USD>0.7616052506</USD>
  </date>
  <date value="2019-07-22">
    <USD>0.7647459939</USD>
  </date>
</rates>
<start_at>2019-07-20</start_at>
<base>CAD</base>
<end_at>2019-07-26</end_at>
```

If we go this route we might also want to change the `<USD>` tag to something like `<currency code="USD">`.

Comment: Hi Razvan.  Thank you very much for your help on this!  You answered my question. Most greatly appreciated. Best regards.

Comment: Please upvote the helpful answers and mark the one that solves your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @RazvanSocol,  It was much better to change `<date2019-07-23>` to something along `<date value="2019-07-23">`. Using tags to carry the workload is in almost any case a really bad idea... I plused your answer, but you might add to this...